# $X,Y$ are standard normal random variables, the correlation is $0.5$. Given $X$, what's the conditional distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

The following is an interview question:

> $X,Y$ are standard normal random variables, the correlation is $0.5$. Given $X$, what's the conditional distribution of $Y$?

I have no idea how to start this question at all.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: This is a fair question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Aaron that without being familiar with some necessary background material, the answer isn't going to make much sense. However, it is still worth mentioning that there is no consistent answer to this question.

This is a usual caveat / nuance when dealing with several normal random variables: you must know in advance that they are **jointly** Gaussian, or else have it be some indirect consequence of what you do know. Otherwise, strange things can happen.

In this case, if $X$ and $Y$ happen to be jointly Gaussian, then the conditional distribution is of course Gaussian (this is a theorem that one ought to be able to at least understand its meaning, see [Aaron's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496827/x-y-are-standard-normal-random-variables-the-correlation-is-0-5-given-x/3496869#comment7191151_3496834) to user658409's answer) and its parameters can indeed be deduced as hinted by [user658409's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496834/738867).

On the other hand, if $X$ is a standard Gaussian and $Z$ is a discrete random variable that is independent of $X$ and satisfies
$$ Z =
\begin{cases}
1,    & \text{with probability } 0.75,\\
-1,    & \text{with probability } 0.25,
\end{cases}
 $$
then one can readily check that $Y=ZX$ is also a standard Gaussian, the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $0.5$, but the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is just discrete: $X$ with probability $0.75$, and $-X$ with probability $0.25$. This is a variation of a simple classical example.

Comment: You are, of course, correct here, and it is quite important to note that the covariance of two random variables will not tell you their joint distribution. An important special case of this observation s that variables can be uncorrelated without being independent, and there are a few important theorems where you can weaken the hypotheses from independent to uncorrelated

Comment: @Aaron Exactly. This is often forgotten in the Gaussian context, since this general warning does not apply to jointly Gaussian random variables. It's a subtlety that is not exactly confusing, but just easy to forget.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write out the distribution. It is a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) with mean vector $\mu =\langle 0,0\rangle$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&1/2\\1/2&1\end{pmatrix}$. You can then just use the undergraduate definition of conditional distribution.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with conditional distribution. It would be great if you can provide the final answer.

Comment: @Idonknow It sounds like you need to learn about conditional distributions, then, and not have someone else do your homework.

Comment: @Aaron The question was asked during interview. So, it is not homework. You can find exactly the same question at glassdoor for JPMorgan quantitative research position.

Comment: @Idonknow Fair enough, but the final answer won't be useful to you on it's own, and any competent interviewer wouldn't accept an answer without an explanation of how you came to it, especially knowing that interview questions get posted online.  A solution won't be comprehensible to you if you don't understand conditional probability, joint distributions, finding conditional distributions from joint ones, etc, and trying to remember one without understanding the underlying the material will be impossible.  You are asking for something that just will not be helpful.

Comment: @Aaron its a fair question i think, you wont have found the direct answer by googling conditional distributions

Comment: @Permian If the question is "What is the conditional distribution in this situation," and you don't know what a conditional distribution is, then the question is NOT a reasonable question. And perhaps more to the point, there is no way that someone here can give a reasonable answer to a person who doesn't have any relevant background.  You CAN google conditional distributions to begin learning, get basic definitions, examples, etc.  It wouldn't be a single search to get all the background and the answer (unless you read some lecture notes), but it would be a necessary start. (cont)

Comment: @Permian (cont) If someone asked "How do you show that $e^{-x^2}$ doesn't have an anti-derivative in elementary functions?" and then admitted that they didn't know what a derivative or anti-derivative was, it would not be a fair question, because we cannot teach all the relevant calculus and differential Galois theory required to answer it in a single post.  A question like "Where could I learn about this topic?" or "What are some keywords I can google?" would be fine.  But a question that you are not in principle qualified to understand the answer of is not appropriate.

Comment: my point is just that looking through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution (and similar online) doesnt get you the answer directly